# What is the equivalent to connecting/reading to a Bluetooth with Delphi

Tags: python, delphi, bluetooth

What I am trying to accomplish is, connect and read data from a (UNKNOWN) Bluetooth device. It is a None commercial or a non-known device, but as of yet I am communicating with it via Python 2.7.9 (w/ BlueZ) and then forwarding the data comprised of binary, and trans-coding it into JSON Array and then forwarding it over a local TCP port (0.0.0.0:1234).

```
...
import socket
import struct
import json
import bluetooth
device = "10:00:E8:6B:F9:F9"
port = 1

btsocket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)

print "Attempting to connect to " + device + "  Port: " + str(port) + "...", btsocket.connect((device, port))
print "done."
while True:
  try:
    btbuffer = btsocket.recv(1024) ## 1024
  except bluetooth.BluetoothError, b:
    print "Bluetooth Error: ", b
```

What is the equivalent code matching this for Delphi 10 Seattle. I have seen code online that tries to communicate with Bluetooth devices when the Device sends back its device name and details. But these details are not provided and the applications fail or pass Exception errors. All it has to do is allow for a known mac address and be able to listen for never ending sensory data. These are the apps I have tried [Device Sensors and Services](https://github.com/Appmethod/Appmethod115/tree/master/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Samples/Device%20Sensors%20and%20Services/Bluetooth)